# Where should I create NSArray for using as DataSource in my TableView

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, datasource

could anybody explain me: where should I create NSArray (I would like to use it in my ViewController class in DataSourseDelegate's methods).

I tried to create it in init, viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear methods, but or get error or this array is empty.

My controller .h file:

```
@interface SendingController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
NSArray *arrDataSource;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *arrDataSource;
```

Or maybe is there the better way in such situation: I use tableView in Navigation interface, and number of section, it names (I use this Array right here) and rows in section defined value (I need table view only to choose disclosure indicator in row to push new controller in Nav stack). How and where should I predefined names of section etc ?? In DataSourceDeleagte's methods ?

Comment: Found solution to work: in ViewDidLoad should use: self.arrDataSource =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:...]; but I used without preceding self. :(  But second part of question is still actual.

Answer (score 0):

The data source of your table view is actually designed for returns such names. The `UITableViewDataSource` protocol defines in particular two methods :

`-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;`
`-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;`

These methods are optionals, but surely, if you want to display any string either in the section header or in the footer, use them. The `UITableViewDataSource` protocol is documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).